# Can I change a div's opacity, when hovering over another div in css?

Tags: css

I have a div containing an unordered list, and a div containing an image. I want to be able to make the image go transparent when I hover over the list.

Is that possible using css, or do I need to use jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your image goes after the list you can do this - http://jsfiddle.net/WYqSu/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<p> some text </p>

<div id="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div:hover ~ div#image {
    opacity: .2;
}
```

Comment: sure it will :) just change the 2nd div id in the CSS to the new one. Instead of `div#image` do `div#yourID`

Answer (score 1):

If the image-div is contained inside the ul-div you can use CSS otherwise you need to use a JS.

```
<div id="divtop">
 <ul>
  <li>listitem</li>
 </ul>
 <div id="divinner">
  <img />
 </div>
</div>

<style>
 #divtop:hover #divinner>img
 {
    /* set opacity */
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used javascript to achieve a similar result:

```
javscript:

function changeOpacity (opacity) {
        document.getElementById("element_ID_to_alter").style.opacity = opacity;
    }

HTML:

<div id="hover_div" onmouseover="changeOpacity('.3')" onmouseout="changeOpacity('1.0')">
```

I'm really pleased with the results from this. I hope it helps you out!